# Laravel REST API Handle Queries

Tags: php, laravel, rest

I'm creating REST API with Laravel 5.6 (I have to say I'm new because I might have used the wrong terms.)

I have get method like this , with this method I can get all parties :

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/parties

but I want to get specific query like this :

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/parties?party_category=club

How can I handle my queries ?

```
class PartiesController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
      $parties = Parties::all();
       return Fractal::includes('places')->collection($parties,new PartyTransformer);
    }

    public function show(Parties $parties) {
      return Fractal::includes('places')->item($parties,new PartyTransformer);
    }

}
```

My route :

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::post('/register',['as' => 'register', 'uses' => 'RegisterController@index']); 

Route::group(['namespace' => 'Parties', 'prefix' => '/parties', 'middleware' => ['auth:api']], function(){
    Route::get('/',['as' => 'parties', 'uses' => 'PartiesController@index']); 
    Route::put('/',['as' => 'parties.store', 'uses' => 'PartiesController@store']); 
    Route::get('/{parties}',['as' => 'parties.show', 'uses' => 'PartiesController@show']);
    Route::get('/{user}',['as' => 'user.show', 'uses' => 'PlacesController@show']); 
    Route::post('/{parties}',['as' => 'parties.update', 'uses' => 'PartiesController@update']); 
    Route::delete('/{parties}',['as' => 'parties.destroy', 'uses' => 'PartiesController@destroy']); 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if `party_category` exists on `url` or not.

```
public function index(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
   if($request->has('party_category')){
      $parties = Parties::where('party_category', $request->party_category)->get();//your new query here
   }
   else{
      $parties = Parties::all();
   }
   return Fractal::includes('places')->collection($parties,new PartyTransformer);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) , I understand how it work now.